# How can I combine multiple splitting criterion when using Haskell package split?

Tags: haskell

i use `Data.List.Split` from `split` on `Hackage` to split a text into sublists at ". " (period followed by blank) with

```
split (keepDelimsR $ onSublist ". "  )
```

but I would like to split on multiple sequence (i.e. "? " (question mark, blank), possibly others.
From the documentation in split i cannot see how to use multiple (more than one character) conditions to split.

Anybody knows a solution? Thank you!

Comment: I don't believe the library itself offers a way to combine `Splitter`s sensibly. Perhaps it is time to upgrade to a real parser.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with break and a lambda expression like

```
break (\t ->   isPrefixOf' "a"  t
            || isPrefixOf' "ab" t
            || isPrefixOf' "aac" t
       ) input
```

not really nice nor clever, but does the trick.
Note: `break` has similar functionality as `split` but expects a condition as argument.